# How to debug Jasig CAS LDAP authentication issues?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, cas

I am following guide at https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html (ad-authenticator) to set up a local CAS SSO server using MS Active Directory.
I managed to run it without any error, but any logon fails with "Invalid credentials" and the following in the log:

```
INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] -
 <AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating username>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - 
 <AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler exception details: \
   No user can be accepted because none is defined>
```

I think I misconfigured some LDAP parameters but have no idea which one. How to debug such kind of problems?

I have the following logger

```
<Logger name="org.ldaptive" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
</Logger>
```

Even if I set root logging level to trace there are no LDAP errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed this piece
https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html#configuration

Add your handler to the list of handlers.